# Is there a way to determine how much memory JVM is allowed to obtain from the underlying OS?

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm

Is there a way to know what is an upper limit (i.e. maximum size) of a physical memory (RAM), that JVM instance (i.e. any Java process) is allowed to obtain from the OS it runs on?

Is it unlimited and Java will take as much as it needs during runtime or there is some limitation (predefined/pre-calculated size of memory) OS imposes on what size of memory it will possibly allocate to java, at most?

If there is, I understand, that it <strike>will</strike> may be different for different Operating Systems, but my question refers to whether there is such a possibility at all or not.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean and how you intend to use this info? Do you mean virtual memory or physical memory? "is allowed" by whom? JVM does not differ from any other process in the OS wrt. memory limits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First of all, probably yeah - it's a good point to be specific about the *type* of the memory, so I've edited my question accordingly. Example: I started some java app, as `java -jar myjarfile.jar` and it is running. What if it consumes more and more.. occupies more and more RAM memory? is there any limit OS will impose or it/OS will give out the space of memory as much as needed? if there is also some peculiarity with respect to virtual (that is heap - I guess?) memory, I would love to hear that as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: About *how I intend to use* - do not have a specific aim right now, but I think I may find this information useful.. if, let's say, something crashes due to some low-level memory related issue.. at least, I will have a chance to know whether Java takes enough memory it needs or not.

Comment: Well the possibility exists.  For example, one of the ways to limit (virtual) memory usage is `ulimit` and a process can find our what its virtual memory ulimit is.  Of course, you won't find out if the OS will *be able to* give a process the memory it asks for ... until it asks for it.  The ulimit is a limit not a commitment.  Hence, knowing your JVM processes ulimit is not particularly useful.

Comment: Another way that (Linux) memory is limited is using cgroup process memory and swap limits.  The same caveats apply as for ulimit.  In addition cgroups limits are on a group of processes not (say) just your JVM process.  And then there are the physical limits of how much RAM you have and how much space on the swap device(s).

Comment: In short ... the *general* answer is that this is not practical on (for example) Linux.